# Large SVN checkout fails sporadically

Tags: windows, apache, svn, xampp, tortoisesvn

I'm currently experiencing issues during a large, full SVN repository checkout (20GB+), where the checkout process will halt randomly. The repository is composed of many small text files and a few large CSV files.

It's been difficult to narrow down the issue as the error only pops up a few hours into the checkout. From what I've seen, it's not a specific file that halts the process and verifying using svnadmin returned no errors.

**Errors:**

*Typical Apache Error Log:*

```
Unable to deliver content.  [500, #0]
Unable to deliver content.  [500, #0]
Could not write data to filter.  [500, #175002]
Could not write data to filter.  [500, #175002]
Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response.  [500, #0]
A failure occurred while driving the update report editor  [500, #730053]
```

**Specs:**

*Server:* Windows Server 2003 running XAMPP v1.8.2-5, Apache v2.4, and SVN v1.8.9. It was recently updated from Apache v2.2 and SVN v1.5.3, which was experiencing similar issues.

*Clients:* Windows 7 running TortoiseSVN v1.8.8 x64, recently updated from v1.8.3 x64 which was experiencing similar issues. Command-line SVN v1.8.9.

I'm using the HTTP protocol to perform the checkout.

---

**Things I've tried:**

Setting the "TimeOut" directive on Apache to a higher value (up to 30000 seconds).

Setting the "SVNAdvertiseV2Protocol" directive to off.

Setting the "SVNPathAuthz" directive to off.

Setting the "SVNCompressionLevel" directive to "0".

Comment: We are facing the same problem here with a much smaller checkout (300MB), it contains 38000 files and sometimes (full checkouts, huge updates ...) the above error occurs. Has somebody already find out something about that?

Comment: Related: https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=502827

Comment: I am on Linux and also have this problem. I have this problem with `libapache-svn` 1.6.7. Problem is intermittent. Works on most servers, but doesn't work on one server, which seems to have the same packages and is otherwise identically configured to the servers which work. `mod_deflate` is in use both on the servers where it works, and on the server where it doesn't.

Comment: i think **Could not write data to filter** is related to `mod_deflate` .Have you tried to disable it ?

Comment: I was using an old Java "svnkit" client (different from the question) and I solved it by upgrading "svnkit" from 1.3 to 1.8. I know this was different to the question, but leaving it here, in case anyone, like me, had this problem with svnkit, and finds this question.

Answer (score 17):

We've been running into this same problem recently. So far I think it has been related to newer subversion clients.

Apache dav_svn_module directive

```
SVNAllowBulkUpdates Prefer
```

Seems to help. After adding that into apache conf, no issues have been found. Before that most of the large check outs failed.

I found a discussion thread which explains the problems which are related to subversion clients that are newer than version 1.8.x.
[See the mailing list thread.](http://users.subversion.apache.narkive.com/rnS5uMWA/checkout-update-issues-with-subversion-1-8-server-and-client-via-http)

Comment: @terio: Using Apache 2.4 SVN 1.9 on my server. Was unable to checkout from a SVN 1.9 client, but could checkout from a SVN 1.8 client. `SVNAllowBulkUpdates Prefer` apparently fixed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Apache 2.4 SVN 1.9 also here... I'm glad it helped you. We haven't had any problems with check outs since that setting; now 3 months have passed.

Comment: It did not help me...it saved me! Thanks again.

Comment: Struggled with this for a long time.  Thought it was https:// related... it wasn't.  This did the trick.  Thanks so much!   For google: the client error I was seeing: "svn: E120171: Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication".

Answer (score 4):

I had the following errors:

```
Unable to deliver content.  [500, #0]
Could not write data to filter.  [500, #175002]
```

I didn't even use the `mod_deflate` so that couldn't be it. In my case it turned out to be the authentication (`auth_digest_module`) causing the error. If a `checkout` lasts more than 300 seconds, I would have the above error logged in my Apache server log.

The problem is the default `AuthDigestNonceLifetime 300` directive. See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_digest.html#authdigestnoncelifetime). My solution was to set this directive to infinity: `AuthDigestNonceLifetime -1`

Comment: Confirmed here. We had similar problems with our digest authenticated svn check outs.

Comment: After add both `Timeout` and `AuthDigestNonceLifetime` to the apache conf

    <VirtualHost ...>
    ... ...
    Timeout 30000 
    <Location />
    ... ...
    AuthDigestNonceLifetime -1
    </Location>

Seems that I just finally take over it.

I didn't find out which one make sense specifically, but I am quite sure that it didn't help if only add `AuthDigestNonceLifetime -1` to the config, same error message in apache error.log (just like the topic says)

Comment: I'm seeing the same errors. According to the apache documentation `AuthDigestNonceLifetime` is only valid in `Directory` or `.htaccess`. Which `Directory` ta should I use for SVN requests?

Comment: @Bram, if you further click on "directory", then you see what is meant by it: "A directive marked as being valid in this context may be used inside <Directory>, <Location>, <Files>, <If>, and <Proxy> containers in the server configuration files, subject to the restrictions outlined in Configuration Sections."

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem attempting to do a snv checkout on a moderately sized (500MB) repository using a server consisting of Centos 7.4.1708, Apache 2.4.6, Subversion 1.9.15 and Windows 10 clients using TortoiseSVN 1.9.7 from behind an Apache Reverse Proxy.

The solution for me was to add `SVNAllowBulkUpdates Off` similar to teori's answer.  I attempted to use "*SVNAllowBulkUpdates Prefer*", but when I restarted httpd, it threw an error saying "*SVNAllowBulkUpdates must be On or Off*".  My final SVN/Apache configuration file is:

```
<Location /svn >
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /svn
    SVNAllowBulkUpdates Off
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "SVN Repo"
    AuthUserFile /var/svn/svn-auth-user
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Other thoughts: I do not believe the `Timeout` and `AuthDigestNonceLifetime` settings are directly related to the problem.  I did attempt to use them but neither had any effect.  I specifically experimented with the `timeout`, `keepalive` and `keepalivetimeout` settings on both the SVN host and the reverse proxy host.

The problem may be related to "deflating", but I also disabled it as Tim S. suggested and it also had not effect. The reason I still think it may be related is that, after eliminating the error, I noticed that the number of bytes transferred was substantially greater than before.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an encoding problem of the files according to [this post](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-dev/201401.mbox/%3CCAL55oQEPFZS57ZCKJ7S6wOQEcPQO8ecZt3nwymLgvTfF0d4zMQ@mail.gmail.com%3E) on the subversion maillinglist. You can either look for `AddEncoding x-gzip .gz` entries in your apache config and remove them or add this to your `<Location /svn>…</Location>` entry:

```
RemoveEncoding .gz
RemoveEncoding .Z
```

This was actualy mentioned in the [changelog](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#mod_dav_svn-fsmap), but neither did I care to read this and learned it the hard way…

Answer (score 1):

One other possible cause I discovered for the "Could not write data to filter" errors is a NAT Loopback or Hairpin Loopback.  We have our SVN Repository Server on a guest VM inside an ESXi host.  SVN Clients within the same ESXi host were trying to reference the Repositories using a URL that would resolve out to the internet then "hairpin loopback" back into the LAN and ESXi host.

SVN Client guest VMs on the same ESXi host would consistently get the following errors in /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log when trying to do a TortoiseSVN Checkout:

```
[dav:error] [pid 2204] Unable to deliver content.  [500, #0]
[dav:error] [pid 2204] Could not write EOS to filter.  [500, #104]
[dav:error] [pid 2204] Could not write data to filter  [500, #104]
[dav:error] [pid 1687] Unable to deliver content.  [500, #0]
[dav:error] [pid 1687] Could not write data to filter.  [500, #104]
[dav:error] [pid 1687] Could not write data to filter  [500, #104]
[dav:error] [pid 1686] Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response.  [500, #0]
[dav:error] [pid 1686] A failure occurred while driving the update report editor  [500, #32]
[dav:error] [pid 1686] Broken pipe  [500, #32]
```

The TortoiseSVN logs would simply say:

```
ra_serf: An error occurred during SSL communication
```

Fixed by changing the references to the SVN Repository URL using local IP addresses instead of a URL that resolved out to the internet.  Other SVN clients in the same LAN but were not in ESXi, such as our laptops had no problem with the Loopback, only the SVN clients in ESXi had this error.